# displaying session variable in alert message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, haml, session-variables

I currently have this in my controller:

```
 if c.save 
    session[:success] = "Career updated successfully."
    redirect_to "/career"
```

And this in my view:

```
- if session[:success]
  .alert.alert-success.fade.in
    %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} ×
    %strong Well Done!
    = session[:success]
```

Yet nothing shows up regardless..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wooo Wooo Wooo never user `session` for this kind of job, use `flash` instead ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html)):

```
# in the controller:
if c.save 
  flash[:success] = "Career updated successfully."
  redirect_to "/career"

# in the view:
- if flash[:success]
  .alert.alert-success.fade.in
    %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} ×
    %strong Well Done!
    = flash[:success]
```

A quote from the doc:

> Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next action and then cleared out.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to display the `flash[:success]` in the right view?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use the `flash` and not `session` ;-)

Comment: I have now, I didn't realise it was an option, I'm still pretty new to this :P

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to an instance variable in the controller, and then display that in the view. You also may want to make the session[:success]  a boolean. So it could be something like:

In the controller:

```
 if c.save 
  session[:success] = true
  @status = "Career updated successfully."      
  redirect_to "/career"
```

And in the view:

```
- if session[:success]
  .alert.alert-success.fade.in
  %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} ×
  %strong Well Done!
  = @status
```

But in general something like this is usually accomplished with a flash message.

Comment: first thing: the @status should not be after the redirect. second thing: you're mixing `flash` and `session` ;-)